# Email not working which contains sub domain url

Tags: php, email, subdomain, html-email

I am getting a strange issue in a website.

I have a domain (e.g. http://exaple.com.PQR.co.uk) on which I have built a website using PHP.

Website working fine but issue is in sending email.

I trying to send HTML email as below example ::

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                        <td style="border: none; background-color: #000; padding: 15px; color:#fff; width: 70px;">
                            <a href="#" style="border:none;">
                               <img src="**http://www.example.com.PQR.co.uk/**webservices/icon-70.png" width="70" height="70">
                            </a>
                </td>
                <td style="border: none; background-color: #000; padding: 15px; color:#fff; font-size: 40px;">
                            ABC
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #000; padding: 10px;">
                    Hello User, <br><br>
                    Your account details are as below:<br/><br/>
                    Email ID : test.example@gmail.com<br/>
                    Password : <a href="**http://www.example.com.PQR.co.uk/**webservices/changepassword.php?token=53ce713d7e998">Click here</a> to change password.<br/>
                </td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #000; padding: 10px;"> 
                    Thanks,<br/> 
                    ABC Team
                </td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #EC008C; padding:5px;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This email does not send successfully but mail() returns TRUE.

When I tries to send same email by changing domain to "example.com" instead of "www.example.com.PQR.co.uk" then it works but with "www.example.com.PQR.co.uk" its not working.

Please guide me for this issue. I am not getting where issue is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess this website is a fashion of sub-domains, like... what I assume is your `PQR.co.uk` is the main website, and `example.com` is a sub-domain right? If so, then please check with your server, if sub-domain named example.com has been registered there or not.

Comment: This should work, because, `mail()` function simply sends the message to the DNS SMTP ports, rest is taken care by the servers. PHP has no role in it.

Comment: Yes "example.com" is already registered. And frankly I have not good knowledge of domain and sub-dmain.

Comment: Have you checked if the mail is in a "spam" folder or something like that? Probably it's marked as spam if your subdomain has no MX-Records for example...

Comment: Yes I have checked. but it is not coming in spam.